# How to manage migrations in Flask with Docker Compose?

Tags: python, docker, flask, flask-migrate

I have a simple Flask service that rely on Postgres database, and I am using [flask-migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to manage my migrations. I know I have first to create the migration scripts locally using something like that:

```
flask db init 
flask db migrate
```

And in my `web` service `Dockerfile` I issue `flask db upgrade` when the container start using:

```
CMD flask db upgrade && flask run
```

My `docker-compose.yaml` is:

```
web:
    build:
      context: .
    expose:
      - "5000"
    depends_on:
      - db 

db:
  image: postgres
  volumes:
    - my_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456
```

The only requirement for me is that the `migrate` should not be automated(see the note below), I tried to run it from host, but this is not possible because the database is running on a container, doing that will raise the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "<Database Container name>" to address: Name or service not known
```

How to overcome that? and is there any mechanism I should follow to to manage the migrations with docker?

**Note:** Flask-migrate state that migrations scripts need to be reviewed before being committed (so I think creation of migrations can not be automated):

> The migration script needs to be reviewed and edited, as Alembic
>   currently does not detect every change you make to your models. In
>   particular, Alembic is currently unable to detect table name changes,
>   column name changes, or anonymously named constraints.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an existing container to initialise migrations and generate revision files using something like `docker exec`. The migrations directory will have to be part of the code you put into your final compose container. Then use `upgrade` as part of bringing up your container as you stated.

Comment: You mean I should bind mount my app directory to the container, and execute init and migrate within the running container?

Comment: Before starting the container is not possible to run (init), on the other hand if issued initi and migrate within the container (using exec) also this is not possible because upgrade command will require migrations folder to exist beforehand.

Comment: Yes, you mount your app directory to a container, execute init and/or migrate to generate the files that go into your app directory under the migrations folder. Then start your compose setup like you do with `flask db upgrade && flask run`

Comment: Creating migrations "needs" -> container running "runs" ->  flask upgrade "needs" -> created migrations. So this will not work.

Comment: Perhaps I was not explaining it well, what I meant was to use a different container that has the code mounted but doesn't run flask. You use `exec` or even `exec -it bash` to get into that container to init and generate migrations.

Answer (score 2):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/287) on flask_migrate, and I will quote from @miguelgrinberg (Owner) answer:

> You have three options:
>
> 1. Make a database available to the host so that you can work on your migrations. It does not need to be your containerized database, it can
>      be a mirror of it that you just use for migrations.
> 2. Make the source code accessible to a container in which you run the migrate command as a mounted volume.
> 3. I assume your database files are in your host, correct? You can then start a separate database process in the host using a copy of the
>      files that are mounted on your database container, then you have a
>      local database that you can migrate without containers.
>
> Option 1 requires some tricky database setup. Option 2 requires some
>   tricky container setup. Option 3 is a bit esoteric and also probably
>   tricky to set up.

Then I asked him why this common task is very hard to accomplish, he says:

> What makes it hard is your development environment choice of having
>   everything locked inside containers. I think you need to make a
>   distinction between development and production. On a development
>   machine you should be a bit more open, like for example exporting the
>   database port so that it can be seen by the host.